# Matplotlib Error TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('<U32') according to the rule 'safe'

Tags: python, matplotlib

Excuse me little knowledge in python but im trying to output a csv file([csvfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1TiF.png)) dataset in a 3d graph. my code so far is as follows:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
   fig = plt.figure()
   ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

with open('new3.csv') as csvfile:
readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
next(readCSV)
next(readCSV)
next(readCSV)
XS =[]
YS =[]
ZS =[]
for column in readCSV:
    xs = column[1]
    ys = column[2]
    zs = column[3]

    XS.append(xs)
    YS.append(ys)
    ZS.append(zs)
    ax.scatter(XS, YS, ZS, c='r', marker='o')
    ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
    ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
    ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')

    plt.show()
```

But i keep coming up with the error in the Title. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because you are trying to plot three lists of `str` type objects. They need to be of `float` or similar type, and cannot be implicitly casted. You can do the type casting explicitly by making the modification below:

```
for column in readCSV:
        xs = float(column[1])
        ys = float(column[2])
        zs = float(column[3])
```

Also note that `ax.scatter` should be *outside* the loop, like this

```
    for column in readCSV:
        xs = float(column[1])
        ys = float(column[2])
        zs = float(column[3])

        XS.append(xs)
        YS.append(ys)
        ZS.append(zs)

ax.scatter(XS, YS, ZS, c='r', marker='o')
ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')
```

Otherwise you will end up with a new scatter plot for every row in the `.csv`. I isolated the first 5 rows of your data and plotted them with these modifications to give

[image: 3D Scatterplot]

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped me output the full file.

Answer (score 0):

just for fun, using numpy which by default circumvents your original issue with passing strings to matplotlib, and at the same time compacting the code a bit.

```
raw = """
id,gx,gy,gz,ax,ay,az
0,4.47,-33.23,-77,-106,94
1,-129.04,4.48,-33.22,-78,-94,117
2,-129.04,4.49,33.2,-70,-81,138
3,-129.02,4.49,-33.18,-70,-64,157
4,-129.02,4.5,-33.15,-64,-47,165
"""

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from io import StringIO

# read data
csvfile = StringIO(raw)
d = plt.np.loadtxt(csvfile, delimiter=',', skiprows=2, usecols=[1,2,3])
# instead of csvfile just use filename when using the real file
xyz = plt.np.split(d.T, indices_or_sections=len(d.T))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(*xyz, c='r', marker='o')
ax.set(**{'%slabel'%s: s.upper() + ' Label' for s in 'xyz'})
```